# How do I review my "Store Preferences" for the Steam Summer Sale Stickers quest?

Tags: steam

One of the Steam Summer Sale Stickers daily quests is to review my "store preferences".

> Review your Preferences
>
> You can help the Steam store show you the best stuff by making sure your Store Preferences match your interests.

[image: screenshot of get stickers quest text]

How can I get to this preference page in the steam client or steam website? Searching through steam's help documentation for "Store Preferences" does not turn up anything.

Comment: In my case, on a mobile device, the "Store Preferences" was a link which would redirect ot the Store Preferences page. The same with the "Discovery Queue" in the quest above that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your preferences can be accessed from a button on the store's front page.

[image: Preferences!]

Comment: I don't know how i missed that... ><

Comment: It's okay, I didn't notice it until I started looking for it in order to answer this question.

Comment: I would imagine there is also a way to edit them through your account or profile as well.  I'm not at my computer at the moment to check.

Comment: @TimmyJim Yes, the store button links directly to the appropriate tab in your profile's preferences.

Comment: They no longer have this button on the home page.  BlueRaja's answer is the correct one for the long term.

Answer (score 16):

The "Store Preferences" portion of the text you highlighted is a link, and will take you to the preferences page. Upon visiting it, you'll get the sticker pack.

Answer (score 16):

The more usual method, that will continue working after this sale is over:

[image: Preferences (steam)]

And from the web-interface:

[image: Preferences (web)]

Comment: the method in the answer of Danmaku is independent from the sale as well.

Comment: @Federico I think BlueRaja was referring to the answer from mmathis.

Comment: @Dorus ah, I missed that there was a third answer.

Comment: @Federico Actually I was talking about Danmaku's answer.  [There was no 'edit preferences' button there](http://www.techspot.com/images2/news/bigimage/2016/11/2016-11-07-image-19.jpg) before the sale.

Comment: I was sure I had seen it before. I guess we will be able to check again after the sale.

Comment: @Federico The sale is now over, and the button in the top answer is gone :P

Comment: I guess that I must have had too much to drink that day then :/ sorry